# Filter SES delivery SNS by original environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

We have different environments that all use same SES to send emails. We are looking for a way to filter the delivery notifications that SES sends back to the topic we have created so that they end up in the correct SQS of each environment.
We tried adding a header to the message but unfortunately SNS topic filter only works with message attributes that we have no control over when SES publishes the delivery notification. How can we achieve this? How can we filter delivery notifications by original environment that has sent the email?